# .Net Runtime Optimization Service Is Turning My System Unstable

Tags: .net, optimization, windows-vista

I'm using Windows Vista Ultimate and today I've installed the Visual Studio 2008 SP1, now that I restarted my computer, it's very unstable and when I got in the Task Manager I see that it's taking 88% of my CPU! **What I can do to solve this?** Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you just wait patiently for a few minutes for the new .Net assemblies to get NGEN'd, and then things will settle back to normal.

Comment: Related: [How and when does ngen.exe work?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20620348/1497596)