# Application exe not running properly. There is a log in CLR_v4.0_32\UsageLogs. What does this mean?

Tags: windows

I have an EXE application we use that is very important.  On some PC's it runs fine -- some it doesn't.  I have seen it work on fresh install of Win7x64 -- after installing the 180 updates it no longer runs properly.

I upgraded to Windows 10 and it ran fine.  Had a hardware problem and had to reinstall the OS.  After doing drivers,updates,etc the application won't run.

I found a log file in: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\CLR_v4.0_32\UsageLogs`

```
1,"fusion","GAC",0
1,"WinRT","NotApp",1
3,"System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","C:\windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System\08da6b6698b412866e6910ae9b84f363\System.ni.dll",0
3,"System.Core, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","C:\windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Core\f6ebd52be27fe627fed0d185c6a9c0d5\System.Core.ni.dll",0
3,"Microsoft.VisualBasic, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","C:\windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\Microsoft.V9921e851#\02386c57c46556747a75089068a31af0\Microsoft.VisualBasic.ni.dll",0
3,"System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a","C:\windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Drawing\c2abcda8f96d67fa6ff5665fd21dddff\System.Drawing.ni.dll",0
3,"System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","C:\windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Windows.Forms\c02fbf560e52a1aab432a90d4c613af4\System.Windows.Forms.ni.dll",0
3,"System.Runtime.Remoting, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089","C:\windows\assembly\NativeImages_v4.0.30319_32\System.Runt73a1fc9d#\272d1cf3a7cbd4cd648a2ff2d7a8889a\System.Runtime.Remoting.ni.dll",0
```

I can't find much information on why these logs are created and if this shows any useful information as to why it's not running properly.  The application is not supported so I'm trying to get it to run until we have another solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think this log file has nothing related to the issue that your application "doesn't run fine".
You should build in your application your own kind of tracing to locate the issue, what kind of exception is raised? Could you provide maybe more information about whats going wrong?

Here are some information about the log file mentioned above:

> With Windows 8 (.NET 4.5), a new NGen mode: "Auto NGen" has been
>   introduced. Basically, the .NET runtime generates usage logs for
>   managed applications. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20620348/how-and-when-does-ngen-exe-work)

[image]

> Every time the application run it creates a new type of logs called
>   “Assembly Usage Logs” in the AppData windows directory.
>   [Source](https://eknowledger.wordpress.com/2012/05/04/clr-4-5-net-framework-kernel-improvements/)

On my research I found out mostly that it **only does this job on Windows 8+**.

But in this [source](http://www.book-ebooks.com/products/reading-epub/product-id/3832817/title/Microsoft%2B.NET%2B4.5%2BUpdate.html) it says also on *Windows Server 2012*, but I have tried it on a *Windows Server 2012 R2 and could **NOT** reproduce it*!